# How do i convert a toml [Table] to a dictionary in C#?

Tags: c#, toml

I would like to read/convert a table form a Toml file into a `dictionary<Tkey, Tvalue>`.
Here is an example for the Toml Table:

```
    [Parameters]
    param1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
    param2 = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

I'm using Tomlyn as the TOML parser. I can add link if it's allowed.

The problem i have is to parse my table "Parameters" to a dictionary. What am i doing wrong?

Here is my attempt:

````
```

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Tomlyn;
using Tomlyn.Model;

void main {
static void Main(string[] args) {


var toml = File.ReadAllText("parameters.toml");

TomlTable model = Toml.ToModel(toml);

// This is what i can't figure out to do correctly
Dictionary<string, object> databaseDictionary = model["Parameters"].ToDictionary();

// Print the contents of the dictionary
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> pair in databaseDictionary)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
}
}

```
````

Thx
Mike/

Comment: ToDictionary() is not availabe  in TomlTable.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Does it compile? Does it give the wrong output?

Comment: @Jay Does not compile - as Mohamed writes it does not have the ToDictionary() method.

Comment: @MohamedFathallah - Sorry, it did not. But i know what to do know, i think. I'll post tomorrow.

Comment: @MohamedFathallah, you code did work. But not the way i was expecting. Mainly due to me lacking experience. The value in you solution is an TomlArray and i needed a list. so based on you answer i was able to modify it to my needs and then combine that with a list of dictionaries that holds all possible combinations. I could add my code but not sure where to put it in the tread..? As an answer maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `Tomltable` doesn't have the Todictionary() method. You need to make a workaround.

You can use `Dictionary<TomlKey, TomlObject>` to initialize a dictionary first instead of `model["Parameters"].ToDictionary();`, then start iterating over your table and inserting its values into the dictionary. as follows:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var toml = File.ReadAllText("parameters.toml");
        
        TomlTable table = Toml.Parse(toml);
        TomlTable parameters = table.Get<TomlTable>("Parameters");

        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var kvp in parameters)
        {
            string key = kvp.Key.ToString();
            object value = kvp.Value.ToObject();

            dictionary.Add(key, value);
        }

        // Print the contents of the dictionary
        foreach (var pair in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{pair.Key}: {pair.Value}");
        }
    }
}
```